# Output for finding Sum of the subarray do not come as Expected

Tags: java, arrays, string

> Prateek wants to give a party to his N friends on his birthday, where each friend is numbered from 1 to N. His friends are asking for a gift to come to the party, instead of giving him one. The cost of the gifts are given in the array Value where ith friend asks for a gift which has a cost Costi.
>
> But, Prateek has only X amount of money to spend on gifts and he wants to invite his friends which are in continuous range such that sum of the cost of the gifts of those friends will be exactly equal to X.
>
> If he can invite his friends, who can satisfy the above condition then, print YES otherwise print NO.

```
  Input:
```

> The first line contains a single integer T, denoting the number of test cases. In each test case, the following input will be present: - The next line contains two space-separated integers N and X, where N represents the number of friends and X represents amount of money which Prateek can spend on gifts. 
>   - Next N line contains N integers, where ith line contains ith integer, which represents the Costi .

```
Ouput
```

Output exactly T lines, each containing the answer to the corresponding test case .

```
Constraints:
1 <= T <= 10
1 <= N , Costi <= 106
1 <= X <= 1012

Sample Input(Plaintext Link)
 1
 5 12
 1
 3
 4
 5
 2

Sample Output(Plaintext Link)

YES
```

**MyApproach**

I followed what is said to take the input and took the subarry sum for every element.But I am not getting Expected output.

```
public static void counCondition()
{   
    boolean b1=false;
    int Sum=0;
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    int T=sc.nextInt();
   for(int i=1;i<=T;i++)
  {
            sc.nextLine();
     String nextLine = sc.nextLine();          //@Edited my mistake 
      String[] input = nextLine.split("\\s+");
      int p = Integer.parseInt(input[0]);
      int c = Integer.parseInt(input[1]);
    int Cost[]=new int[p];
    for(int j=0;j<Cost.length;j++)
    {
       Cost[j]=sc.nextInt();
    }
    for(int k=0;k<Cost.length;k++)
    {
         Sum=0;
        for(int l=k;l<p;l++)
       {
           Sum=Sum+Cost[l];
            if(Sum>c)
            {
                break;
            }
            else if(Sum==c)
                   {
                       b1=true;
                       break;
                   }
       }
    }

     if(b1==true)
     {
         System.out.println("YES");

     }
     else
     {
         System.out.println("NO");
     }
  } 
  sc.close();
 }
```

//@Edit Output is still the same.

```
 **ActualInput**            **ExpectedInput**

 1                          1
 5 12                       5 12
 1                          1
 3                          3
 4                          4
 5                          5
 2                          2
 6
 7
 8 
 9
 2                          

 **ActualOutput**           Expected Output(Plaintext Link)

   NO                    YES
```

I am not expecting this output.

> Can anyone guide me why?

Answer (score 1):

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
>   at app.HackerEarth25Dec2015.counCondition(HackerEarth25Dec2015.java:18)

The exception is occurring because you are calling `next()` method not the `nextLine()`. The `next()` method return the next token which `5` here not the complete line.

Also I would suggest you to use the `nextInt()` from the Scanner instead of getting the String and splitting and parsing it. That would be a cleaner way of doing things.

```
  int p = sc.nextInt();
  int c = sc.nextInt();
```

> **Also your logic is also not correct. I hope you will find the logical error and fix it.**

---

You can use the below code for fixing the issue.

```
sc.nextLine(); // This is to read the `\n` left from previous `nextInt()`
String nextLine = sc.nextLine();
String[] input = nextLine.split("\\s+");
```

Comment: Hobbit By using nextLine()  It should be passed in String array or String?I have to collect the input from 5 as well as 12.I don't think it requires sc.next() as it will take separate input.

Comment: `nextLine()` also returns `String` only. Just that complete line. Then you can split it by white space. I would suggest you to use `nextInt()` which I have provide in the answer.

Comment: I have to take input from the line of String.I need to convert it.That is given in the question

Comment: For that use `nextLine()` and parse the `String` after the `split(" ")`.

Comment: Dude I would suggest you to use `nextInt()` all the places as you know that all the number are integers. Otherwise it will be little complicated. You need to read the `new line character (\n)` after each of the `nextInt()` which you are doing for reading the number of test cases.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98974/discussion-between-jason-arora-and-younghobbit).

Comment: @Jasonarora May I know the reason for removing the acceptance from answer.

Comment: See Your Chat.I have messaged you

Answer (score 1):

Once you have got the individual cost in the Cost array.
Here is the logic to get continous sum equal to max sum.

Maintain a start index variable telling from where continous sequence is starting. In the start it should be zero index.

Maintain sum variable to track the total sum.

Run a for loop from zero to endIndex.

if sum less than max sum

Add Cost[i] to sum.

else if sum equals max sum, break the for loop

else if sum greater than max sum

Now remove elements from startIndex till sum again becomes less or equal to max sum using while loop.

while(sum > maxSum)

sum = sum - cost[startIndex]

increment startIndex

while loop finished

if sum equals maxsum, break the loop you got your answer

else continue the outer for loop.

The idea of this logic is to keep removing elements from start from the sum whenever sum increases the maxsum.

Answer (score 1):

```
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
  int t=sc.nextInt();
  while(t>0)
  {
   int n=sc.nextInt();
   long x=sc.nextLong();
   long[] money=new long[n];
   for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
   {
    money[i]=sc.nextInt();
   }
   long sum;
   int c=0;
   sum=money[0];
   for(int i=1;i<n;i++)
   {
    if(sum<x)
     sum=sum+money[i];
    else if(sum==x)
     break;
    while(sum>x)
    {
     sum=sum-money[c];
     c++;
    }
   }
   if(sum==x)
    System.out.println("YES");
   else
    System.out.println("NO");
   t--;
  }
```

here http://jayarampandava.blogspot.in/2015_10_01_archive.html
you can find the actual solution